# Display data from mysql into ListView in Android

Tags: java, android

I am currently fetching data from mysql database and displaying successfully in the TextView like this:

```
private void showJSON(String response){

        String child_name="";
        //String address="";
        //String vc = "";
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(config.JSON_ARRAY);
            JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
            child_name = collegeData.getString(config.KEY_NAME);
            //address = collegeData.getString(config.KEY_ADDRESS);
            //vc = collegeData.getString(config.KEY_VC);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        textViewResult.setText("Children Name:\t" + child_name);
```

now, rather into the TextView, I want to display it in the ListView. So How to proceed in this way as i am new to android development.

Answer (score 0):

In order to populate a ListView in Android you first need to create an Adapter object where you'll define the layout of each item and the behavior of the list.

Basically what you'll have to do is:

1. Create an ArrayList of the objects you want to display
2. Create an Adapter for your list view (passing the previously created list as parameter at creation)
3. Set the adapter to your ListView object.

You may follow this guide for the complete details: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html